# How can I change start week day on a graph? (plotly.js)

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

How can I change start week day on a graph? Now I have only Sundays on xaxis. I need to display only Mondays on xaxis. Thank you. My plotly config is:

```
...
xaxis: {
    type: 'date',
    automargin: true,
    tickformat: '%d.%m',
    maxPadding: 1,
},
yaxis: {
    tickmode: 'array',
    automargin: true,
    showticklabels: false,
    showgrid: false,
},
...
```

Comment: where is the data array that you're feeding it? plotly.js charts/graphs are looking for a trace object which would defined your data being plotted x/y in this case.  so I imagine you'd have trace = {x : ['Sun','Mon','Tue'...], y: [other data]}

Comment: I have array format YYYY-MM-DD. Example i see 16.04.2020, but see only Sundays. How can i edit it? (on xaxisx, on yaxis i have data 100, 200, 400)

Comment: please past the array here

Comment: ```
[
 {value: "2020-04-16", count: 100}, 
 {value: "2020-04-17", count: 200},
 {value: "2020-04-18", count: 300},
 {value: "2020-04-19", count: 400},
 {value: "2020-04-20", count: 500},
 {value: "2020-04-21", count: 600},
 {value: "2020-04-22", count: 700},
 {value: "2020-04-23", count: 800},
 {value: "2020-04-24", count: 100}, 
 {value: "2020-04-25", count: 200},
 {value: "2020-04-26", count: 300},
 {value: "2020-04-27", count: 400},
 {value: "2020-04-28", count: 500},
 {value: "2020-04-29", count: 600},
 {value: "2020-04-30", count: 700},
]

Comment: Example. In xaxis i have dates and see only Sundays ...
traces: [
      {
        x: [],
        y: [],
        type: 'bar',
 }
]
...

Comment: I think "sunday " is a default, are you sure it can take in an array of objects.  just to see what happens feed it x:['sun','mon','tue','wed'...], if that works try x:['2020-04-01','2020-04-02'.....].  isolate the issue and find out if problem is format of array or input date.

Comment: how i can change this default value "sunday" ? I will try change object and write here

Comment: try x: abovePrintedArray.map(rec => rec.value) ....this should give it an array of the values.

Comment: dont work with another format (

Comment: really nobody faced this problem?

Comment: Hello. How I solved this: Because my language wasn't supported directly I have created a local repo of plotly and changed default values to my language (days and months names). There is variable "firstDay" too and needs to be changed from 0 to 1. There are more firstDay variables, you need to find the correct one. I know it is not clean solution but I don't need to use other languages.

Comment: 1. make loacal copy of plotly and edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned their repo and used your data array  As I mentioned in my notes, it's just a matter of formatting what you're feeding your x/axis, I used moment in my example below, I'm sure you can use other ways to get the date format you'd like.

let me know if something about below code needs further clarification. BTW. I'm using react version, but at a quick glance they both looked like the same setup.

```
      const PlotlyClass = (props) => {
  let VasilyBasicArray = [{ value: "2020-04-16", count: 100 }, { value: "2020-04-17", count: 200 }, { value: "2020-04-18", count: 300 }, { value: "2020-04-19", count: 400 }, { value: "2020-04-20", count: 500 }, { value: "2020-04-21", count: 600 }, { value: "2020-04-22", count: 700 }, { value: "2020-04-23", count: 800 }, { value: "2020-04-24", count: 100 }, { value: "2020-04-25", count: 200 }, { value: "2020-04-26", count: 300 }, { value: "2020-04-27", count: 400 }, { value: "2020-04-28", count: 500 }, { value: "2020-04-29", count: 600 }, { value: "2020-04-30", count: 700 }]


 return (
<Plot
  data={[
    {
      x: VasilyBasicArray.map(rec => moment(rec.value).format('dd-Do')),
      y: VasilyBasicArray.map(rec => rec.count),
      type: 'scatter',
      mode: 'lines+markers',
      marker: { color: 'red' },
    },
    { type: 'bar', x: VasilyBasicArray.map(rec => moment(rec.value).format('dd-Do')), y: VasilyBasicArray.map(rec => rec.count) },
  ]}
  layout={{ width: 320, height: 240, title: 'A Fancy Plot' }}
/>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: i tried format date (how you showed in your example), but it not work in my graph

Comment: did you import momentJs package?

Comment: if you have imported moment js https://momentjs.com/ and still can't get it to work, I'll need to see your full code to see what's wrong, or better yet post a link to your repo

Answer (score 0):

1. Make a local copy of plotly.
2. Find text: GregorianCalendar.prototype (or your default calendar).
3. In this prototype find variable firstDay (there are many firstDay variables in the file) and change value from 0 to 1.

This is not clean solution but it works if you don't need to use other languages.
In this prototype you can rename months and days too if you need.